# Movement from memory into a register. Why do I need explicit prefix for the in-memory operand?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

I am compiling the next snippet

```
.data
k db 'Hello, world!',13,10,0
.code
mov ax,word ptr ds:[k]
```

It is explicitly pointed that I move a word into `ax`. Since we know that `ax` takes 2 bytes, why do I need to point that out in the in-memory operand?

Comment: You don't, unless `k` has been defined with a different type but you did not show that. I believe masm is trying to be helpful in catching type mismatch errors.

Comment: You don't need the `ds:` prefix, only the `word ptr` operand-size override.  (And yes, as Jester says that's because MASM "variable" declarations (label + db / dw / dd / dq) imply a size, unlike if you use `k:` `db ...`, if MASM allows that.  (Support for a `:` in that context might vary by version, I don't remember the full details of explanations of if/how you can get MASM to *not* treat labels as "variables").